# Sorting the list by alphabet ascending order

Tags: java, sorting, lambda

my code below doesn't work, and I can't figure out why.

It compiles well, but the result doesn't seemd to be sorted.

```
import java.util.*;

class SortByName {
  public static void main (String[] args) {
    List<String> nameList1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Joe1","Abe1", "Steven1", "Patrict1"));
    List<String> nameList2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Joe22","Abe2", "Steven2", "Patrict2"));

    Comparator<String> comparator1 = (name1, name2)-> { return name1.length() - name2.length(); };
    nameList1.sort(comparator1);


    Comparator<String> comparator2 = Comparator.comparingInt(String::length);
    nameList2.sort(comparator2);

    nameList1.forEach((str)->System.out.println(str));
    nameList2.forEach((str)->System.out.println(str));
  }
}
```

Comment: how is that not work, can you explain more ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is sorting by String length,
output should be,

**For List1**

```
Joe1
Abe1
Steven1
Patrict1
```

**From List2 :**

```
Abe2
Joe22
Steven2
Patrict2
```

If you wanna sort this by alphabetical order then edit your code,

```
Comparator<String> comparator1 = (name1, name2)-> { return name1.compareTo(name2); };
```

Answer (score 1):

You are performing comparison by string length, which is working nicely, as your output is sorted from shortest string to longest string. If you are trying to sort alphabetically you want to use the String classes built in compare function. This would look like:

```
Comparator<String> comparator1 = (name1, name2)-> { return name1.compareTo(name2); };
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort list in alphabetic order, you can use below comparator

```
 Comparator<String> comparator1 = (name1, name2) -> {
        return name1.compareTo(name2);
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the followings

```
Comparator<String> comparator1 = (name1, name2)-> { return name2.length() - name1.length(); };
Comparator<String> comparator2 = Comparator.comparingInt(String::length).reversed();
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the Javadoc for `Comparator`:

> Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

Neither of your Comparators do this.

Write tests to directly call `compare` on each of your `Comparator`s, in at least the three scenarios `a>b, a=b, a<b`, and make sure they return 1, 0 or -1 in the right scenarios. Only then should you use them in a sort.

Having said that, the default comparator for String is alphabetical, so you'd get an alphabetical sort of you didn't specify one.

Answer (score 0):

using JAVA 8

```
List<String> nameList1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Joe1", "Abe1", "Steven1", "Patrict1","a"));     
List sorted=nameList1.stream().sorted((s1,s2)->s1.compareTo(s2)).collect(Collectors.toList());
sorted.forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));
```